# Unhandled event loop exception in Eclipse when trying to build Maven project

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse

I've set up a simple Maven project and am trying to build it when I run into an error with Eclipse.

message:

> Unhandled event loop exception

stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DevClassPathHelper
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenEmbeddedRuntime.addBundleClasspathEntries(MavenEmbeddedRuntime.java:193)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenEmbeddedRuntime.initClasspath(MavenEmbeddedRuntime.java:127)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenEmbeddedRuntime.getVersion(MavenEmbeddedRuntime.java:283)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenEmbeddedRuntime.getVersion(MavenEmbeddedRuntime.java:334)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenEmbeddedRuntime.toString(MavenEmbeddedRuntime.java:269)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.LabelProvider.getText(LabelProvider.java:56)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractListViewer.getLabelProviderText(AbstractListViewer.java:187)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractListViewer.inputChanged(AbstractListViewer.java:325)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.setInput(ContentViewer.java:292)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setInput(StructuredViewer.java:1675)
at org.eclipse.m2e.ui.internal.launch.MavenRuntimeSelector.<init>(MavenRuntimeSelector.java:80)
at org.eclipse.m2e.ui.internal.launch.MavenLaunchMainTab.createControl(MavenLaunchMainTab.java:394)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.showInstanceTabsFor(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:817)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.displayInstanceTabs(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:748)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer$8.run(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:635)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.inputChanged(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:652)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.setInput0(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:613)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.setInput(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:588)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationPropertiesDialog.initializeContent(LaunchConfigurationPropertiesDialog.java:104)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.createContents(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:446)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:435)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1101)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.create(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:374)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:797)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.open(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:1154)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationPropertiesDialog.open(LaunchConfigurationPropertiesDialog.java:213)
at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.openLaunchConfigurationDialog(DebugUITools.java:694)
at org.eclipse.m2e.actions.ExecutePomAction.launch(ExecutePomAction.java:157)
at org.eclipse.m2e.actions.ExecutePomAction.launch(ExecutePomAction.java:127)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension.launch(LaunchShortcutExtension.java:431)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.LaunchShortcutAction.run(LaunchShortcutAction.java:74)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.LaunchShortcutAction.runWithEvent(LaunchShortcutAction.java:123)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1085)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1070)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:782)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$9.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:1293)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DevClassPathHelper cannot be found by org.eclipse.m2e.core_1.4.0.20130601-0317
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:423)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:336)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:328)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 69 more
```

It looks like it's being caused by the m2eclipse plugin but I am not sure. I'm using Luna 4.4.0 with m2eclipse version 1.5.0.20140606-0033. How to fix?

Comment: @DarshanLila there isn't any code triggering this, it's a problem within org.eclipse.ui

Comment: Have u added dependencies and plugins?

Comment: Looks like Eclipse bug [412436](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=412436) which is marked as fixed, but it looks like the problem in `MavenEmbeddedRuntime` may have been missed.

Comment: @greg-449 is there anyway i can work around this?